# Change widgets with opacity in stack by swap

Tags: flutter

On swapping opacity of image changes. How can I do this function ? I tried pageview , stack.

First page:
[image: first page]

Swapping to next page:
[image: swaping to next page]

Second page:
[image: second page]

Comment: You want scrolling images like above screen shots

Comment: yes , I used pageview but it doesnt work like this

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using `TweenAnimationBuilder`, `PageView` and `Opacity` widgets. Something like this:

```dart
PageView(
  children: [

    _Page1(),
    TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(
        begin: 0,
        end: 1,
      ),
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 1,
      ),
      builder: (context, value, _) => Opacity(
        opacity: value,
        child: _SecondPageHere(),
      ),
    ),
    
  ],
);
```

The `TweenAnimationBuilder` animated from its tween `begin` value to its `end` (in this case, 0 to 1) when it shows up.

In this case, it will animate from 0 opacity to 1 opacity as it builds.

EDIT: this should work better for your case

```dart
late PageController controller;
  double opacity = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = PageController();
    controller.addListener(_onPageScroll);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onPageScroll() {
    if (controller.page == null || controller.page! > 1) return;
    setState(() {
      opacity = controller.page!;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      controller: controller,
      children: [
        Image.asset('image1'),
        Opacity(
          opacity: opacity,
          child: Image.asset('image2'),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: I did same thing. its works, but doesnt like on screenshots

Comment: @DjasurDjinabev what's the difference?

Comment: @DjasurDjinabev check if the edit works for you

Answer (score 0):

If i used pageview with opacity
[when swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ArRv.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).